# Can I move Bootstrap Carousel to the right instead of center?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm using Bootstrap Carousel, but not sure if it is possible to move the Carousel to the far right instead of putting it in the center. I've looked for an example of it but I could not find any other than moving the indicator to the right. I'd like to move the whole Carousel to the right, so I can have white space on the left. Can I do this with Bootstrap Carousel? Or should I look for some other way?

```css
.mainCarousel {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="mainCarousel">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/1.jpg" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/1.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could wrap your carousel in another container and move that.

Comment: @sarah kim your code snippet seems broken?

Comment: @sarah kim: you have the whole 12 column grid system (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/) to construct the layout.

Comment: what carousel library are you using?

Comment: @LaurentC I'm using Bootstrap Carousel.. not sure library?

Comment: @DavidLiang I actually tried a grid system in there, but it would not give me the results of how I wanted. It always made my carousel very small...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only just want to have **non-writable** whitespace on the left of the carousel, use the accepted answer's approach. In fact, you don't even need to set the width to 75%. You can just add left paddings to the carousel.

If you want to have space on the left of the carousel so that you can put some texts there, and you want it to be responsive, use the grid system to construct the layout, and place the carousel on the right column.

The following is just an example. I have no idea how long you want the carousel to be, and/or when you want the left stacks up on top of the right column:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            Writable area
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="mainCarousel" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At large breakpoint and up:

[image]

Below large breakpoint:

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/sj541uoL/7/

Comment: Hi Thank you so much, so I tried another grid system (there were so many and I think tried all) but could not find the right size. And I feel like it's like a word document, I move something to the right then everything gets messed up! But I think the one you suggested works the best.

Comment: Credits to Bootstrap framework. I do think it's the best out there. I would highly suggest you read through their documentations. After that, you would have lots of new ideas how you want to construct your layout :)

Answer (score 3):

Add these 2 classes `.w-75` `.ml-auto` to `.mainCarousel` see the example.
And if you don't want `.w-75` which contains `width: 75% !important;` you can add custom `width` to `.mainCarousel` in your CSS.

```css
.mainCarousel {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="mainCarousel w-75 ml-auto">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1051399/pexels-photo-1051399.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2741458/pexels-photo-2741458.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2175211/pexels-photo-2175211.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```